# How to change Linux hot key

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I would like to know if it is possible to change the hot key on a Linux distribution.

I have already tried to re-configure the hot keys in the virtual box preferences but i have not been able to accomplish the results i am looking for.

I am currently running a Linux Antergos in a Virtual Box and i would like to change the hot key to match the ⌘ key of Mac Book Pro to improve workflow and swap the workstation hot key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Overall i would like to be able to save files in the Virtual Machine using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> Etc...

Comment: I see.. Antergos is using KDE by default at least it seems... Search 'KDE keymap' and related posts if you ARE using KDE.

Comment: http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-runtime/fundamentals/shortcuts.html